# Translating sql to linq

Tags: sql, linq, entities

I'm new to the Linq world and I can't figure out how to convert the following sql to linq due to some constrain in the database that affect adding some fields I need:

```
select sp.SessionID,
    sp.SessionParticipationID,
    case when z.SessionParticipationID = sp.SessionParticipationID then 1 else 0 end as RecordedFL
from SessionParticipation sp
inner join (
    select sp1.SessionID,
        sp1.SessionParticipationID
    from Meeting.SessionParticipation sp1
    inner join RegistrantActivity ra on ra.SessionParticipationID = sp1.SessionParticipationID
    where ra.RegistrantID = 12345
) z on z.SessionID = sp.SessionID
```

The entities are SessionParticipation and RegistrantActivity

Comment: Spend a little time here (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). You'll learn what you need to know.

Comment: I've been there already, and I didn't see any way to replicate a case statement in linq

Comment: @user1286550: if you struggeling with the **case** please have a loot at this **http://lancefisher.net/blog/archive/2008/05/07/linq-to-sql---case-statements.aspx**

Comment: Is `Meeting` a schema? What is `Meeting.SessionParticipation`?

Comment: not your answer but try "linqer" http://www.sqltolinq.com/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like

```
from sp in SessionParticipations
join z in
(from sp1 in MeetingSessionParticipations
join ra in RegistrantActivities on sp1.SessionParticipationID equals 
                                   ra.SessionParticipationID
where ra.RegistrantID = 12345
select sp1)
on sp.SessionID equals z.SessionID
select new { 
             sp.SessionParticipationID,
             RecordedFL = z.SessionParticipationID == sp.SessionParticipationID
                          ? 1 : 0
           }
```

assuming that `Meeting.SessionParticipation` is a different table in a different schema than `SessionParticipation`, otherwise the join makes things needlessly complex. (Although identical table names in different schemas is... confusing).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. There is not a Case statement in Linq but I can use the the ?: operator.